# Can I depend on GCM service to create a big instant messaging application ?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

If I want to create an instant messaging application using android, is it a good and efficient  to use the `Google Cloud Messaging API` ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of mentions in `GCM` documentation and tutorial saying that is no guarantee of order and success receive of messages. Like here:

> Note that since there is no guarantee of the order in which messages
>   get sent, the "last" message may not actually be the last message sent
>   by the application server.

I suggest you use this as a call to update user chat e.g. when your app get a `GCM` you request your server-side to get the new messages but not transfer messages by `GCM` itself also because you have some dayly limits as well.

See more here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

I found the mention above here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html. At description of `collapse_key` here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html#params

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works for Google and you won't have to maintain servers. If your message is short, in can be included in the GCM message. Otherwise the GCM could be a payload to notify your app to check for a new message.